# Get Area Description File (Debug) in Unity and reuse it to match 3D object onto real world

Tags: unity-game-engine, tracking, google-project-tango

I would like know if there is a way to see the ADF file in Unity in order to place precisely my 3D object on the real tracked object ?
Thx.

Answer (score 1):

You will find everything you need to know here: https://developers.google.com/tango/overview/area-learning

And in the sample code found here:
https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity/blob/master/UnityExamples/Assets/TangoSDK/Examples/AreaLearning/Scripts/AreaLearningInGameController.cs#L453